# Get unicode value from a character in a string using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, unicode

I have the following string which is Arabic:

عضو منذ ‏14 نوفمبر، 2009

At first glance it appears that there is a space before the number 14 but this is not true. I have not been able to determine what this character is. I have tried isEmpty, isBlank, .equals(""), == null but nothing returns true. How can I retrieve the unicode value of the character at that position? To extract just the character I do this:

```
memberSinceText.substring(8, 9)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look at the characters one by one and print their unicode-counterpart, using:

```
val memberSinceText = "عضو منذ ‏14 نوفمبر، 2009"

memberSinceText.toCharArray()
  .forEachIndexed { pos, c ->
    println("$pos. $c -> ${String.format("\\%04x", c.toInt())}")
}
```

we get an output similar as to follows (adapted it a bit and added some comments; due to the values in the same line it isn't that easily copy&pasteable):

```
 0. ع -> \0639
 1. ض -> \0636
 2. و -> \0648
 3.   -> \0020 // Space
 4. م -> \0645
 5. ن -> \0646
 6. ذ -> \0630
 7.   -> \0020 // Space
 8. 200f\ <-   // actually omitting the symbol here due to copy&paste-problems
 9. 1 -> \0031
10. 4 -> \0034
11.   -> \0020 // Space
12. ن -> \0646
13. و -> \0648
14. ف -> \0641
15. م -> \0645
16. ب -> \0628
17. ر -> \0631
18. ، -> \060c
19.   -> \0020 // Space
20. 2 -> \0032
21. 0 -> \0030
22. 0 -> \0030
23. 9 -> \0039
```

So actually... there is a space before and after `14`, but there is also some other special character at position 8. If we look what that basically is, we get (after applying our RTL-vision): `\u200f` which is basically the right-to-left-mark.

Printing that symbol alone with some context:

```
memberSinceText.substring(8, 9).also {
  println(">$it|")
}
```

will print: `|<` (note the direction). Printing the `substring(7,8)` however, will give you your space character: `> |`